# Does my website need a custom login feature if I'm using Facebook authentication?

Tags: facebook, web

My site already has a Facebook authentication feature, allowing people to login using their Facebook accounts. Works perfectly, for certain people who have FB accounts. Is it a good practice to provide only FB authentication option? What are the pros and cons?

Actually, I need to convince my customer that FB login is enough, and we don't need any additional "login forms". Would be nice to show him some articles/researches that prove my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggyback authentication is a growing trend among web applications.  It really depends on who your audience is.  For example, if your web application is related to open source projects, it would be quite reasonable to require users to use Github authentication.

If your service's primary function relies on Facebook integration, I would say yes it's okay to only have FB auth.  However, if it's just an "option" like linking your profile to your well FB profile, then having a primary custom login would be the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to be honest in most cases where you really want a high conversion rate you can't force your users to be a member of any particular auth provider, i.e facebook. And you should rather implement a hybrid, federated login system by which your users can choose there preferable auth provider like "Google","Yahoo","OpenId","Facebook","Twitter"

If you want to spend money and dont want to spend time on coding, you may check out existing solutions which are proven to work good like JanRain Engage. Otherwise, if you are building application using PHP then you can use a hybrid authentication library like [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net) which is not only free+open-source but also supports OpenID, Facebook, Google, Twitter, MySpace and AOL based authentication system.

I hope you will find it useful. Just my $0.02 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good idea. What if FB changes its login method? Your site will be out meanwhile you are fixing the problem.

My best experience is to have my own login schema/database and link some other methods (as FB, twitter, google, etc.) to simplify the login process for users (but been linked to unique own user for my database). So, if some access method fails you can use your own identifier to login.

Comment: that's why they are not changing it all of a sudden. They publish their new technology and slowly deprecate the old one.